# Cannot solve ODE question with Initial Value

Tags: differential-equations

I'm using Mathematica to solve the ODE problem y'=xy, y(1)=2.

However, when I put my equation into Mathematica, it only appears 'True'.I tried it the webpage http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/ and it was fine but I could not solve it on my computer. I attached my pic below

How do I solve this equation using DSolve?

[image]

Comment: Please put in code in `InputForm[]` that can be copied by other people; don't make people have to retype your expressions just to help you. Also, you seem to have accidentally done `y[1] = 2` instead of `y[1] == 2` (note the difference!!!) in a previous computation; evaluate `Clear[y]` and try again.

Comment: `y` is black, which means it has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting the kernel, and restarting.  Your code works on my version of Mathematica (11.2.0.0).

```
eqn1 = {y'[x] == x y[x], y[1] == 2}
```

[image]

```
DSolve[eqn1, {y[x]}, {x}]
```

[image]